# ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION dialog: how do I cancel? Android 11 Java settings dialog?

Tags: java, android, settings

I have decided I am in Android 11 and do not yet have this permission. I do the intent stuff for my URI and the dialog opens up. I have got a timeout counter decrementing while the Android settings dialog is shown. When it times out, I have not yet found a way to end the dialog programmatically. There is no cancel button and the back button does not get the dialog off the screen either. I can't close the app either: all the methods I've tried just leave the dialog staring at me.

I have a similar problem with requestPermissions for regular permissions. The user has to go through all the required permissions. We are working with people whose skills are not computer/smartphone related, we're trying to keep it simple.

Comment: Those dialogs are system-supplied, launched by the OS. They are not part of your app. Your app cannot control them, any more than you can control third-party activities that you start.

Comment: It appears that once that dialog comes up, I have no option but to kill the app, no matter what I do to the slide box? There appears to be no way out of this Android function.

Comment: Permission dialog is actually a floating activity that's started for result, it's not a dialog within your activity.